# What is a fancy way to say "same sign" for two numbers?

Tags: terminology, arithmetic

If $xy > 0$, then $x$ and $y$ are [*insert fancy smart term for same sign*]

Does "sign parity" work here?

Comment: I've never heard anyone use the phrase, "sign parity".

Comment: That's because I made it up lol...

Comment: ... then $x$ and $y$ have the same sign. Why complicate things?

Comment: I have seen $xy \gt 0$ being used to denote that they have the same sign!

Comment: Why do you need a fancy smart term? Just say they have the same sign.

Comment: Because I want to look smart on my HW...

Comment: There are plenty of other ways to accomplish that goal. I second @Aryabhata's suggestion, though.

Comment: If you just absolutely have to have an english term for this, I would use "have matching signs."  Though $xy > 0$ seems better to me...

Comment: Doing artificial things to try and "look smart" usually only works on people who are clueless about the material. On everybody else, it tends to have exactly the opposite effect.

Comment: "either both positive or both negative"...Anyhow the best way to look smart on a HW is by keeping thing neat, SIMPLE, and making no mistakes ;)

Comment: I find it legitime (and common) to introduce nouns to denote something as fixed-term property. For instance x "is positive" after fiddling many times with "x has positive sign". Another instance x and y "are correlated" in a text, where the according observation of how their values jointly behave was discussed. (This is just the power of abstractions). A natural candidate for some noun/adjective for two numbers having the same sign would be "are like-signed", or "are same-signed". (But that's surely not much creative at the moment...)

Comment: While I agree with most of the comments made so far that there is no fancy commonly accepted term for this relation, and as a general principle it's best not to complicate things, I do think the OP has asked a perfectly reasonable question. There might have been a non-obvious standard term after all, and to communicate efficiently it is good to learn standard terminology. After all, there are non-obvious 'fancy' terms in mathematics which the eager student of mathematics might like to familiarise him/herself with. For example...

Comment: ...$b^2-4ac$ is called the discriminant of $ax^2+bx+c$, though I personally didn't know this till after I'd seen hundreds of quadratics.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A quick search in Google Books gives the following quote:

> [..] Hence, if $\Delta_{r-1}$ and $\Delta_r$ **are of opposite signs**, $\Delta_{r+1}$ and $\Delta_{r+2}$ **are of the same sign as** $\Delta_r$ [..]

You can't be smarter than [H. S. M. Coxeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harold_Scott_MacDonald_Coxeter)!

Comment: It even rhymes!

Comment: Yes, but what did Gauss use?

Comment: ...or you could say they are "of like sign"...

Answer (score 3):

If $x$ and $y$ are real numbers, then the followings are equivalent.

- $xy>0$.
- $x$ and $y$ are both nonzero, and cannot have differing signs.
- The closed line segment connecting $x$ and $y$ does not contain $0$.
- One can go from $x$ to $y$ without ever touching $0$.
- The intervals $[x,y]$ and $[-x,-y]$ have no common point.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with user2468. Usually this is stated $x$ and $y$ have the same sign. sgn($x$)=sgn($y$) could also be used. [Weisstein, Eric W. "Sign." From MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sign.html
]
Also "sign parity" would be confusing since "parity" is used to refer to even or oddness.